# Visual Studio ridiculously slow debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am attempting to debug a program in VS2010 using a breakpoint with a boolean condition. This particular breakpoint is painfully slow, making my program run hundreds of times slower than without the condition or using a regular unconditioned breakpoint.

My question is, is this a common issue with visual studio, I can't believe the debugger can be this slow? The boolean expression is very simple, it simply says break the program when i == x inside a for loop.

Any help appreciated as it's making debugging very painful.

Thanks
Richard

```
        public static RawNetCalculationResults newCATXLNets(IList<Loss> RawLosses, IList<ReinsuranceProgramme> Programme) //Loss contains the properties Year, EventID, Loss Value
    {
        List<Recoveries> NetRawLosses = new List<Recoveries>(RawLosses.Count * Programme.Count);    //Initiate list with required capacity

        //Loop over each element in RawLosses List and do some calculations
        foreach (var e in RawLosses)
        {                           //<----BREAK POINT HERE (e.Year == x)
            foreach (var layer in Programme.Where(x => x.Type == ReinsuranceType.CATXL))
            {
```

Comment: It probably isn't the debugger. Can you show us the code?

Comment: I edited my question with the code. I have one breakpoint on the outer loop. So when the property of an element in the outer loop reaches x (x is an int representing the property Year contained in the List<Loss>). Removing the breakpoint means my code runs very fast (matter of seconds for the entire loop), adding the single breakpoint means it takes around 20minutes.

Comment: Found a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391419/visual-studio-slow-down-the-execution-when-use-conditional-break-points

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, conditional breakpoints are slow.

As an alternative, you can use Debug.Assert:

```
Debug.Assert( i != x );
```

This will cause the assert to fire when `i == x` and you can debug from there.

Comment: I prefer: `if (condition) Debugger.Break();`

Comment: Works great, I ended up using Debugger.Break for the exact functionality. Somewhat strange the breakpoints themselves are so slow compared to this.

Comment: Apparently this have to do with actual physical hardware that's being used  for debugging - not something I would have guessed.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/501675/Whyplusareplusconditionalplusbreakpointsplussoplus